# How to Rename multiple files

Tags: rename

I have hundreds of images which I want to rename:

- Current name `A0619101`. Rename to `A1906101`
- Current name `A0825223`. Rename to `A2508223`

Actually the first and second digits must become third and fourth. And the third and fourth digits must become first and second.

Could you help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to rename multiple files sequentially from command line?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/301781/how-to-rename-multiple-files-sequentially-from-command-line)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the current directory contains all files you wish to rename:

```
rename 's/^A(\d\d)(\d\d)/A$2$1/' *
```

Take care: this algorithm cannot *swap* file names, so if you have files `A1122333` and `A2211333`, then afterwards the second will be gone and the first will still be called `A1122333` (having be renamed twice).

The following script fixes that issue:

```
rename 's/^A(\d\d)(\d\d)/tmp-A$2$1/' *
rename 's/^tmp-//' *
```