# Rename returns "bareword not allowed" when trying to lowercase parts of multiple filenames

Tags: command-line, files, rename, batch-rename

I have two files in a folder on my Ubuntu 16.04:

```
a1.dat
b1.DAT
```

I want to rename `b1.DAT` to `b1.dat` so I would have following files as a result in the folder:

```
a1.dat
b1.dat
```

I tried (unsuccessfully):

```
$ rename *.DAT *.dat
Bareword "b1" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at (user-supplied code).
Bareword "DAT" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at (user-supplied code).
```

and

```
$ find . -iname "*.DAT" -exec rename DAT dat '{}' \;
Bareword "DAT" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at (user-supplied code).
Bareword "DAT" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at (user-supplied code).
```

Searching for this resulted in no meaningful solution...

Comment: You also might want to learn about mmv

Answer (score 31, accepted):

That error looks like it comes from Perl `rename`. You need to use quoting, but you only need to specify the part you want to change, search-and-replace style. The syntax is like this:

```
rename -n 's/\.DAT/\.dat/' *
```

Remove `-n` after testing to actually rename the files.

To include hidden files, change glob setting before running the command:

```
shopt -s dotglob
```

If you want to rename files recursively, you can use

```
shopt -s globstar
rename -n 's/\.DAT/\.dat/' **
```

or if there are many paths in or below the current directory that do not end with `.DAT`, you had better specify those paths in the second command:

```
rename -n 's/\.DAT/\.dat/' **/*.DAT
```

This will be faster if your files have various different names not ending in `.DAT`.<sup>[1]</sup>

To turn off these settings you can use `shopt -u`, eg `shopt -u globstar`, but they are off by default and will be off when you open a new shell.

If this results in an excessively long argument list, you can use, for example, `find`:

```
find -type f -name "*.DAT" -exec rename -n -- 's/\.DAT/\.dat/' {} \;
```

or better

```
find -type f -name "*.DAT" -exec rename -n -- 's/\.DAT/\.dat/' {} +
```

Using `find ... -exec` with `+` is faster than using `\;` because it constructs an argument list from the found files. Originally I thought that it wouldn't be possible for you to use it, because you mentioned that you were having an `argument list too long` issue, but now I know that the list will also be cleverly broken into multiple invocations of the command as needed to avoid that problem<sup>[2]</sup>.

Since `rename` will process every filename in the same way, it does not matter how long the argument list is as it can be safely split across multiple invocations. If the command you are using with `-exec` does not accept multiple arguments or requires its arguments to be in a particular order or for any other reason splitting the argument list will cause something unwanted to happen, you can use `\;`, which causes the command to be invoked once for every file found (if the argument list was too long for other methods, this will take a long time!).

---

**Many thanks to [Eliah Kagan](https://askubuntu.com/users/22949/eliah-kagan) for the very useful suggestions to improve this answer:**

<sup>[1]</sup> [Specifying the filenames when globbing](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43735979#43735979).
<sup>[2]</sup> [`find ... -exec` with `+` splits the argument list](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43736040#43736040).

Comment: Thanks. How to do it recursively (for all the files in all the subfolders)?

Comment: @Samo see my edit :)

Comment: Not working: $ rename 's/\.DAT/\.dat/' **
bash: /usr/bin/rename: Argument list too long

Comment: @Samo oh ok. Lots of files. You can use `find` (edited again!)

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. Commands run without error but file names are not changed.

Comment: @Samo you need to remove the `-n` from rename after testing - it's just to show what will be changed

Comment: On Centos and Arch, rename doesn't exhibit this behavior. I got here from using Debian on WSL. This syntax worked.

Answer (score 9):

You can do:

```
rename -n 's/DAT$/\L$&/' *.DAT
```

Drop `-n` for actual renaming to take place.

- glob pattern `*.DAT` matches all files end in `.DAT` in the current directory
- in the `rename`'s substitution, `DAT$` matches `DAT` at the end
- `\L$&` makes the whole match lowercased; `$&` refers to the whole match

If you just want to do for `b1.DAT`:

```
rename -n 's/DAT$/\L$&/' b1.DAT
```

**Example:**

```
% rename -n 's/DAT$/\L$&/' *.DAT
rename(b1.DAT, b1.dat)
```

Answer (score 8):

[Other](https://askubuntu.com/a/1015695/22949) [answers](https://askubuntu.com/a/1015694/22949) have addressed one of the two major aspects of this question: that of how to successfully carry out the renaming operation you needed. The purpose of this answer is to explain why your commands did not work, including the meaning of that weird "bareword not allowed" error message in the context of the `rename` command.

The first section of this answer is about the relationship between `rename` and Perl and how `rename` uses the first command-line argument you pass it, which is its code argument. The second section is about how the shell performs expansions--specifically globbing--to construct an argument list. The third section is about what is going on in Perl code that gives "Bareword not allowed" errors. Finally, the fourth section is a summary of all the steps that take place between entering the command and getting the error.

#### 1. When `rename` gives you weird error messages, add "Perl" to your search.

In Debian and Ubuntu, the `rename` command is a [Perl](http://foldoc.org/perl) script that performs file renaming. On older releases--including 14.04 LTS, which is still [supported](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#Current) as of this writing--it was a [symbolic link](http://foldoc.org/symlink) pointing ([indirectly](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives)) to the [`prename`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/prename.1.html) command. On newer releases, it points instead to the newer [`file-rename`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/file-rename.1p.html) command. Those [two Perl rename commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229230/whats-with-all-the-renames-prename-rename-file-rename) work mostly the same way, and I'll just refer to them both as `rename` for the rest of this answer.

When you use the `rename` command, you're not just running Perl code someone else has written. You're also writing your own Perl code and telling `rename` to run it. This is because **the first [command-line argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Arguments) you pass to the `rename` command, other than [option arguments](http://foldoc.org/option) like `-n`, *consists of actual Perl code***. The `rename` command uses this code to operate on each of the [pathnames](http://foldoc.org/pathname) that you pass it as subsequent command-line arguments. (If you don't pass any pathname arguments, then `rename` reads pathnames from [standard input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_(stdin)) instead, one per line.)

The code is run inside [a loop](http://foldoc.org/loop), which [iterates](http://foldoc.org/iteration) once per pathname. At the top of each iteration of the loop, before your code runs, the special [`$_` variable](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables) is assigned the pathname currently being processed. If your code causes the value of `$_` to be changed to something else, then that file is renamed to have the new name.

Many [expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_(computer_science)) in Perl operate implicitly on the `$_` variable when they are not given any other expression to use as an [operand](http://foldoc.org/operand). For example, the substitution expression `$str =~ s/foo/bar/` changes the first occurrence of `foo` in the string held by the `$str` [variable](http://foldoc.org/variable) to `bar`, or leaves it unchanged if it does not contain `foo`. If you just write `s/foo/bar/` without explicitly using [the `=~` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Binding-Operators), then it operates on `$_`. This is to say that `s/foo/bar/` is short for `$_ =~ s/foo/bar/`.

It's common to pass [an `s///` expression](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) to `rename` as the code argument (i.e., the first command-line argument), but you don't have to. You can give it any Perl code you wish for it to run inside the loop, to examine each value of `$_` and (conditionally) modify it.

This has a lot of [cool and useful consequences](https://askubuntu.com/a/1017507/22949), but the vast majority of them are well beyond the scope of this question and answer. The main reason I bring this up here--in fact, the main reason I decided to post this answer--is to make the point that, because the first argument to `rename` is actually Perl code, anytime you get a weird error message and you have trouble finding information about it by searching, you can add "Perl" to the search string (or even replace "rename" with "Perl", sometimes) and you'll often find an answer.

#### 2. With `rename *.DAT *.dat`, the `rename` command never saw `*.DAT`!

A command like `rename s/foo/bar/ *.txt` does not typically pass `*.txt` as a command-line argument to the `rename` program, *and you don't want it to*, unless you have a file whose name is literally `*.txt`, which hopefully you do not.

**`rename` does not interpret [glob patterns](http://foldoc.org/glob) like `*.txt`, `*.DAT`, `*.dat`, `x*`, `*y`, or `*` when passed to it as pathname arguments.** Instead, [your shell performs pathname expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) on them (which is also called filename expansion, and also called globbing). This happens before the `rename` utility is run. The shell expands globs into potentially multiple pathnames and passes them all, as separate command-line arguments, to `rename`. In Ubuntu, your interactive shell is [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)), unless you have changed it, which is why I've linked into the [Bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/) above.

There is one situation where a glob pattern may be passed as a single unexpanded command-line argument to `rename`: when it does not match any files. Different shells exhibit different default behavior in this situation, but Bash's default behavior is to simply pass the glob literally. However, you rarely want this! If you did want it, then you should *ensure* that the pattern is not expanded, by [quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting) it. This goes for passing arguments to any command, not just to `rename`.

Quoting is not just for globbing (filename expansion), because there are [other expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions) that your shell performs on unquoted text and, for [some of them but not others](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Double-Quotes), also on text enclosed in `"` `"` quotes. In general, anytime you want to pass an argument that contains characters that may be treated specially by the shell, including spaces, you should quote it, preferably with [`'` `'` quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Single-Quotes).

The Perl code `s/foo/bar/` does not contain anything treated specially by the shell, but it would have been a good idea for me to have quoted that too--and written `'s/foo/bar/'`. (In fact, the only reason I didn't was that it would be confusing to some readers, as I had not yet talked about quoting.) The reason I say this would have been good is because it's very common that Perl code *does* contain such characters, and if I were to change that code, I might not remember to check if quoting was needed. In contrast, if you want the shell to expand a glob, it must *not* be quoted.

#### 3. What the Perl interpreter means by "bareword not allowed"

The error messages you showed in your question reveal that, when you ran `rename *.DAT *.dat`, your shell expanded `*.DAT` into a list of one or more filenames, and that the *first* of those filenames was `b1.DAT`. All the subsequent arguments--both any others expanded from `*.DAT` and any expanded from `*.dat`--came after that argument, so they would have been interpreted as pathnames.

Because what actually ran was something like `rename b1.DAT ...`, and because `rename` treats its first non-option argument as Perl code, the question becomes: why does `b1.DAT` produce these "bareword not allowed" errors when you run it as Perl code?

```
Bareword "b1" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at (user-supplied code).
Bareword "DAT" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at (user-supplied code).
```

In a shell, we quote our strings [to protect them](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/171347/11938) from unintended [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions) that would otherwise transform them into other strings automatically (see the section above). [Shells are special purpose programming languages that work very differently from general-purpose languages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169765/11938) (and their [very weird syntax and semantics](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/66387?m=40934461#40934461) reflect that). But Perl is a [general-purpose programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General-purpose_programming_language) and, like most general-purpose programming languages, the main purpose of quoting in Perl is not to *protect* strings, but to mention them at all. This is actually a way most programming languages are [*similar* to natural language](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/quotation/#2.2). In English, and supposing you have a dog, "your dog" is a two-word phrase, while your dog is a dog. Similarly, in Perl, `'$foo'` is a string, while `$foo` is something whose name is `$foo`.

However, unlike just about every other general-purpose programming language, Perl will *also* sometimes interpret unquoted text as *mentioning* a string--a string that is the "same" as it, in the sense that it is made up of the same characters in the same order. It will only try to interpret code that way *if it is a bareword* (no `$` or other sigil, see below), and after it couldn't find any other meaning to give it. Then it will take it as a string, *unless you tell it not to* by enabling [restrictions](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html).

Variables in Perl typically begin with a punctuating character called a [*sigil*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil_(computer_programming)), which specifies the broad type of the variable. For example, [`$` means *scalar*, `@` means *array*, and `%` means *hash*](https://perlmaven.com/scalar-variables). ([There are others.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_language_structure#Data_types)) Don't worry if you find that confusing (or boring), because I'm only bringing it up to say that **when a [valid name](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Identifier-parsing) appears in a Perl program but is *not* preceded by a sigil, that name is said to be a *[bareword](http://modernperlbooks.com/books/modern_perl_2016/11-what-to-avoid-in-perl.html#YmFyZXdvcmRz)***.

Barewords serve various purposes, but they usually signify a [built-in function](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-functions.html) or a [user-defined subroutine](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#DESCRIPTION) that has been defined in the program (or in a module used by the program). Perl has no built-in functions called `b1` or `DAT`, so when the Perl interpreter sees the code `b1.DAT`, it tries to treat `b1` and `DAT` as the names of subroutines. Assuming no such subroutines have been defined, this fails. Then, provided [restrictions](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) have not been enabled, it treats them as strings. This will work, though whether or not you actually *intended* this to happen is anybody's guess. Perl's `.` operator [concatenates strings](https://perlmaven.com/string-operators), so `b1.DAT` evaluates to the string `b1DAT`. That is, `b1.DAT` is a bad way to write something like `'b1' . 'DAT'` or `"b1" . "DAT"`.

You can test this out yourself by running the command `perl -E 'say b1.DAT'`, which passes the short Perl script `say b1.DAT` to the Perl interpreter, which runs it, printing `b1DAT`. (In that command, the [`'` `'` quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Single-Quotes) tell the shell to pass `say b1.DAT` as a single command-line argument; otherwise, the space would cause `say` and `b1.DAT` to be [parsed as separate words](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Operation) and `perl` would receive them as separate arguments. `perl` does *not* see the quotes themselves, as [the shell removes them](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quote-Removal).)

**But now, [try writing `use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html)** in the Perl script before `say`. Now it fails with the same kind of error you got from `rename`:

```
$ perl -E 'use strict; say b1.DAT'
Bareword "b1" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at -e line 1.
Bareword "DAT" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at -e line 1.
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

This happened because `use strict;` prohibited the Perl interpreter from treating barewords as strings. To prohibit this particular feature, it would really be sufficient to enable just the `subs` restriction. This command produces the same errors as above:

```
perl -E 'use strict "subs"; say b1.DAT'
```

But usually Perl programmers will just write `use strict;`, which enables the `subs` restriction and two others. `use strict;` is generally recommended practice. **So the `rename` command does this for *your* code.** That is why you get that error message.

#### 4. In summary, this is what happened:

1. Your shell passed `b1.DAT` as the first command-line argument, which `rename` treated as Perl code to run in a loop for each pathname argument.
2. This was taken to mean `b1` and `DAT` connected with the `.` operator.
3. `b1` and `DAT` were not prefixed with sigils, so they were treated as barewords.
4. Those two barewords would have been taken as names of built-in functions or any user-defined subroutines, but no such thing had either of those names.
5. If "strict subs" had not been enabled, then they would have been treated like the string expressions `'b1'` and `'DAT`' and concatenated. **That's far from what you intended, which illuminates how this feature is often not helpful.**
6. But "strict subs" was enabled, because `rename` enables all [restrictions](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) (`vars`, `refs`, and `subs`). Therefore, you got an error instead.
7. `rename` quit due to this error. Because this sort of error happened early, no file renaming attempts were made, even though you had not passed `-n`. This is a good thing, which often protects users from unintentional filename changes and occasionally even from actual data loss.

***Thanks go to [Zanna](https://askubuntu.com/users/527764/zanna)**, who [helped me address several important shortcomings in an ealier draft of this answer](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43737578#43737578). Without her, this answer would have made way less sense, and might not be posted at all.*

Comment: Nailed down to the core points explanations written in a style I would wish all help and info texts were have been  written. Your effort to provide this answer is appreciated. It helped me much to better understand the shell and pearl.

Answer (score 0):

I just had same error. So I land here, saw stuff which can be typical to get used to if your are noob in Linux environment.

I just want short command easier to remember:

```
mv Greetings Greetings.java
```

And that's it. mv command rename the file from Greetings to Greetings.java

No more **Greetings** file. Only **Greetings.java** file ready to compile using **javac**.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
 rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *
```