# Renaming multiple files with Bash

Tags: bash, batch-rename

I have a lot of files to process and I need to replace their original names with this format in bash:

```
00000000000001_1.jpg 
00000000000002_1.jpg
00000000000003_1.jpg
```

and so on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adapted from [one of Oli's answers](https://askubuntu.com/a/478197/507051):

```
rename -n 's/.+/our $i; $i++; sprintf("%014d_1.jpg", $i)/e' *
```

This takes every file in the current directory and renames it with a number with `14` digits (I hope I counted correctly) followed by `_1.jpg`. `our $i` introduces a global variable `i`, which is then increased by one and printed with `sprintf`. `e` commands `rename` to evaluate the right side of the replacement (= everything between the second and the third `/`) as an expression rather than literally. If you're happy with the results, remove `-n` to perform the renaming.

If you want to dive into perl expressions and their beauty, [the perldoc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) is the way to go.

Comment: This is a good approach. The Perl [`rename`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/file-rename.1p.html) utility is powerful, flexible, and fast. Note that [the approach you've shown here can be simplified](https://askubuntu.com/a/1017507/22949) (but it does work just fine, as written).

Answer (score 3):

Would this works for you :

```
i=1
for file in *; do
    mv "$file" "$(printf %014d $i)_1.jpg"
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

It will rename every file in the current directory like this :

```
00000000000001_1.jpg
.
.
00000000000009_1.jpg
.
.
00000000000010_1.jpg
.
.
```

Comment: replace `._$file` with `_1.jpg` and I think you've got it.

Comment: I edited my answer, I thought _1.jpg was supposed to be the original file name.

Comment: Looking better. Just need to change `._1.jpg` to `_1.jpg` then I think it's perfect.