# Copying single files from multiple directories to a new directory with multiple sub directories hosting each file

Tags: command-line

I am attempting to copy a single specific file that is contained within 960 sub directories in a parent directory. Each file has the same name but has unique content.

I want to maintain the hierarchy of the directories and names in the new parent directory, but only want one specific file rather than all the files in each sub directory.

I also need to create each of these sub directories named processorN where N is a number from 0 to 959.

Any ideas, this has stumped me and I can't seem to find a good solution that isn't going to take me hours.

Comment: Hello! Please provide an example of the current and the desired directory structures. For this purpose you can create manually a parent directory and few sub directories and then you can [edit] and update the question with the output of the command `tree /path/to/parent-dir/`.

Answer (score 2):

`rsync` can do that with some tricky `--include` and `--exclude` flags:

```
rsync -a -v --include="*/" --include="specific-file.txt" --exclude="*" from/ to/
```

This will copy all directories and the `specific-file.txt` from `from`
to `to` while skipping everything else. The command will preserve the
complete directory structure below `from` and copy it to `to`. You
may first want to run this with the `-n` switch to see what *would*
happen, i.e.:

```
# check:
rsync -a -v -n --include="*/" --include="specific-file.txt" --exclude="*" from/ to/

# actually do:
rsync -a -v    --include="*/" --include="specific-file.txt" --exclude="*" from/ to/
```

Comment: I've upvoted, but maybe the second requirement *"...sub directories named processorN..."* is not satisfied - probably something as `rename 's/.+/our $i; sprintf("processor%03d", 0+$i++)/e' *` will do the job - [more details](https://askubuntu.com/a/478197/566421).

Comment: @pa4080 Might be. I thought those `processorN` directories were the 960 subdirectories the OP talks about in the first paragraph. He should really clarify that, as you already asked.