# Move files from subfolders

Tags: command-line, bash

I've been beating my head against this for a while, but I'm really not a good script writer.  Apologies...

I'm running Ubuntu/gnome 18.10, and have a large set of pictures exported from my wifey's mac.  The directory structure is:

```
year1
  (login dir name with spaces) - Month
    Image names
year2
  ...
```

as in:

```
2013
  May 4, 2013
    Image1.jpg
    Image2.jpg
  May 5, 2013
    Image 1.jpg
    Image 3.jpg
  June 22, 2013
```

What I would like, is:

```
2013
   January
     All the "january" images...
   February
     All the...
```

I can create the directories easily enough `mkdir {January..December}` suffices.  But I cannot figure out how to walk the ugly directory tree (exported from Mac), move the images, and then delete the ugly directory.

Comment: I'd want to rename the images first, probably adding the full date, otherwise it looks like they'll overwrite each other if moved to a common directory. If the file's dates match their folder's dates that might be easier than using the file's path..

Comment: @Xen2050 Thanks - the file naming has changed over the years as cameras were bought and destroyed...  but I think I have a fairly elegant solution.  It unfortunately does not advance my knowledge of scripting...  `exiftool  '-FileName<DateTimeOriginal' -d %Y/%m-%B/%f%%-c.%%e . -r` -> it's almost perfect, except for some .mov files which do not have exif data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is such script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# The destination where the new directory structure will be created
DEST="/tmp/new-order-pictures/"

MONTHS=('Jan' 'Feb' 'Mar' 'Apr' 'May' 'Jun' 'Jul' 'Aug' 'Sep' 'Oct' 'Nov' 'Dec')

# Walk through the first level directories, located in the current directory and go inside
for year in */
do
    cd "$year"
    # Walk through the months of the year
    for month in "${MONTHS[@]}"
    do
        # Walk through the second level directories
        for dir in */
        do
            # If we have coincidence between the name of the directory and the month
            # go inside, make a new destination directory; ignore character cases^^
            if [[ ${dir^^} =~ ${month^^} ]]
            then
                cd "$dir"
                dest="${DEST}${year}${month}"
                mkdir -p "$dest"
                find . -type f | while IFS= read -r item
                do
                    # Copy the files to the new destination and
                    # add the file's md5sum to its name to prevent files lose
                    filename=$(basename -- "$item")
                    extn="${filename##*.}"
                    name="${filename%.*}"
                    cp "$item" "${dest}/${name}-$(md5sum "$item" | cut -f1 -d' ').${extn}"
                done
                cd ..
            fi
        done
    done
    cd ..
done
```

The script should be executed in the first level directory where your images are located. You should tweak the destination directory - `DEST="/tmp/new-order-pictures/"`. This version of the script relies that all files are in directories that contain the name of a month in one way or another. Example of usage:

```bsh
user@host:~/Pictures$ tree .
.
├── 2013
│   ├── January 17, 2013
│   │   ├── Image1.jpg
│   │   └── Image 3.jpg
│   ├── January 24, 2013
│   │   └── Image2.jpg
│   ├── January 25, 2013
│   │   └── Image 3.jpg
│   ├── June 22, 2013
│   │   └── image1.jpg
│   ├── May 4, 2013
│   │   └── Image1.jpg
│   └── May 5, 2013
│       ├── Image1.jpg
│       └── Image 2.jpg
└── 2014
    ├── January 17, 2014
    │   ├── Image1.jpg
    │   └── Image 3.jpg
    ├── January 24, 2014
    │   └── Image2.jpg
    ├── January 25, 2014
    │   └── Image 3.jpg
    └── May 5
        ├── Image1.jpg
        └── Image 2.jpg

12 directories, 14 files


user@host:~/Pictures$ order.sh 


user@host:~/Pictures$ tree /tmp/new-order-pictures/
/tmp/new-order-pictures/
├── 2013
│   ├── Jan
│   │   ├── Image1-7b71d9fdfe5b15a2d1a4968c195f93ae.jpg
│   │   ├── Image2-cbf4d36ff84e7ec24c05f8181236e6b8.jpg
│   │   ├── Image 3-0bca5188fd3f3eb470533fdaf0630633.jpg
│   │   └── Image 3-6a83880cae1aa57e19a7c45de7759e68.jpg
│   ├── Jun
│   │   └── image1-adb3bf995f1a25d008f758a7266d7be5.jpg
│   └── May
│       ├── Image1-511d541b35fcb38af8ada18d7961268c.jpg
│       ├── Image1-a66c5863e6986605cb2ca6d622ae72a0.jpg
│       └── Image 2-c34ffc32ce5d3901e1ad89b9fd15a877.jpg
└── 2014
    ├── Jan
    │   ├── Image1-7b71d9fdfe5b15a2d1a4968c195f93ae.jpg
    │   ├── Image2-cbf4d36ff84e7ec24c05f8181236e6b8.jpg
    │   ├── Image 3-0bca5188fd3f3eb470533fdaf0630633.jpg
    │   └── Image 3-6a83880cae1aa57e19a7c45de7759e68.jpg
    └── May
        ├── Image1-511d541b35fcb38af8ada18d7961268c.jpg
        └── Image 2-c34ffc32ce5d3901e1ad89b9fd15a877.jpg

7 directories, 14 files
```

In my case the script is named `order.sh` and it is located in `~/bin`, thus I can use it as shell command. In the example you can see the directory structure is changed but the number of files is 14 in both structures.

---

Here is another version of the script that use `mv` instead of `cp` and will deal also with the files which are not in directories that contain the name of a month. Before running this script it is a good idea to create a backup copy of the original directory structure.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# The destination where the new directory structure will be created
DEST="/tmp/new-order-pictures/"

MONTHS=('Jan' 'Feb' 'Mar' 'Apr' 'May' 'Jun' 'Jul' 'Aug' 'Sep' 'Oct' 'Nov' 'Dec')

# Walk through the first level directories, located in the current directory and go inside
for year in */
do

    cd "$year"

    # Walk through the months of the year
    for month in "${MONTHS[@]}"
    do
        # Walk through the second level directories
        for dir in */
        do
            # If we have coincidence between the name of the directory and the month
            # go inside, make a new destination directory; ignore character cases^^
            if [[ ${dir^^} =~ ${month^^} ]]
            then

                cd "$dir"
                dest="${DEST}${year}${month}"
                mkdir -p "$dest"

                while IFS= read -r item
                do
                    # Copy the files to the new destination and
                    # add the file's md5sum to its name to prevent files lose
                    filename=$(basename -- "$item")
                    extn="${filename##*.}"
                    name="${filename%.*}"
                    mv "$item" "${dest}/${name}-$(md5sum "$item" | cut -f1 -d' ').${extn}"
                done < <(find . -type f)

                cd ..

            fi

        done

    done

    # Dial with the rest of the files for that $year

    dest="${DEST}${year}other"

    while IFS= read -r item
    do
        mkdir -p "$dest"
        filename=$(basename -- "$item")
        extn="${filename##*.}"
        name="${filename%.*}"
        mv "$item" "${dest}/${name}-$(md5sum "$item" | cut -f1 -d' ').${extn}"
    done < <(find . -type f)

    cd ..

done
```

Example of usage:

```bsh
user@host:~/Pictures$ tree .
.
├── 2013
│   ├── January 17, 2013
│   │   ├── Image1.jpg
│   │   ├── Image 3.jpg
│   │   └── video 7.mpg
│   ├── January 25, 2013
│   │   └── Image 3.jpg
│   ├── June 22, 2013
│   │   └── image1.jpg
│   └── May 5, 2013
│       ├── Image1.jpg
│       └── Image 2.jpg
└── 2014
    ├── Apr 7
    │   ├── Image1.jpg
    │   └── Image 2.jpg
    ├── Image 2.jpg
    ├── January 11, 2014
    │   ├── Image1.jpg
    │   └── Image 3.jpg
    ├── some other name
    │   └── some other name file inside.jpg
    ├── some other name file inside.jpg
    └── video 1.avi

9 directories, 15 files

user@host:~/Pictures$ order.sh 

user@host:~/Pictures$ tree /tmp/new-order-pictures/
/tmp/new-order-pictures/
├── 2013
│   ├── Jan
│   │   ├── Image1-7b71d9fdfe5b15a2d1a4968c195f93ae.jpg
│   │   ├── Image 3-0bca5188fd3f3eb470533fdaf0630633.jpg
│   │   ├── Image 3-6a83880cae1aa57e19a7c45de7759e68.jpg
│   │   └── video 7-86764d9565469adfb22c8ef4f0b9c04f.mpg
│   ├── Jun
│   │   └── image1-adb3bf995f1a25d008f758a7266d7be5.jpg
│   └── May
│       ├── Image1-511d541b35fcb38af8ada18d7961268c.jpg
│       └── Image 2-c34ffc32ce5d3901e1ad89b9fd15a877.jpg
└── 2014
    ├── Apr
    │   ├── Image1-3c19da25e0e56ef0fc752a9e4f75b190.jpg
    │   └── Image 2-dcc35e86de393a014ac62e8c4390c7e6.jpg
    ├── Jan
    │   ├── Image1-ae34289b0bc5258f286165745ff3c258.jpg
    │   └── Image 3-1724adf2dfcc1d4a0dc50cb38ad2c510.jpg
    └── other
        ├── Image 2-eff5208f7eee6a536e48f9982b918dfb.jpg
        ├── some other name file inside-7d0a68e0b4e9cc3928744cb83f4d1136.jpg
        ├── some other name file inside-c2dd637e94a9025c3e1004d66f59539c.jpg
        └── video 1-c277d93a2427bedf3f0b8ae07427edb9.avi

8 directories, 15 files
```

After that you can go inside the destination directory and use the `rename` command within `for` loop to deal with the long names:

```bsh
# For each directory on the second level
for dir in */*
do
    cd "$dir"
    rename 's/^.*(\.[0-9a-zA-Z]+)$/our $i; sprintf("Image-%03d$1", 1+$i++)/e' *
    cd ..
    cd ..
done
```

Example:

```bsh
user@host:~/Pictures$ cd /tmp/new-order-pictures/

user@host:/tmp/new-order-pictures$ for dir in */*; do cd "$dir"; rename 's/^.*(\.[0-9a-zA-Z]+)$/our $i; sprintf("Image-%03d$1", 1+$i++)/e' *; cd ..; cd ..; done

user@host:/tmp/new-order-pictures$ tree .
.
├── 2013
│   ├── Jan
│   │   ├── Image-001.jpg
│   │   ├── Image-002.jpg
│   │   ├── Image-003.jpg
│   │   └── Image-004.mpg
│   ├── Jun
│   │   └── Image-001.jpg
│   └── May
│       ├── Image-001.jpg
│       └── Image-002.jpg
└── 2014
    ├── Apr
    │   ├── Image-001.jpg
    │   └── Image-002.jpg
    ├── Jan
    │   ├── Image-001.jpg
    │   └── Image-002.jpg
    └── other
        ├── Image-001.jpg
        ├── Image-002.jpg
        ├── Image-003.jpg
        └── Image-004.avi

8 directories, 15 files
```

Or you can change `(\.[0-9a-zA-Z]+)` with `(\.jpg)`, then on next iteration with `(\.mpg)` (respectively `Image-` with `Video-`), etc. References about this usage of `rename`:

- [How to rename multiple files sequentially from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/a/478197/566421)
- [Renaming hundreds of files at once for proper sorting](https://askubuntu.com/a/473355/566421)

Comment: Thanks!  I think this is really close to what I asked for, and I'll have to scour the web looking for shell expansions et al...

Comment: Hi, @CharlesGreen, I"ve updated the answer with few more ideas. Sorry for the long answer and the lack of explanations inside... if you need clarifications about some parts, please ping me :)

Comment: No problem at all - I really am looking to use this more as a reason to learn some shell scripting.  I did in fact find a single line command which does exactly what I need!

Comment: @CharlesGreen: Nice! It will be worth to write an answer.

Comment: I can certainly share the command, and will add it later.  But your command answered a deeper question in prompting me to learn more about scripting

Comment: Added an answer with the command I mentioned in earlier comments.

Answer (score 2):

There is an application which can move and rename the files in a single command line - `exiftool`

```
sudo apt install libimage-exiftool-perl
```

In my case, the specific command line used was

```
exiftool  '-FileName<DateTimeOriginal' -d <path-to-output-dir>/%Y/%m-%B/%Y%m%d_%H%M%S%%-c.%%e . -r
```

or

```
exiftool  '-FileName<CreateDate' -d <path-to-output-dir>/%Y/%m-%B/%Y%m%d_%H%M%S%%-c.%%e . -r
```

depending upon which tag is present in the images.  If the requested tag is not present, the application throws a warning and does not move that file, but continues processing.  This application also handles multiple images with the same date/time by appending a numeric to the end of the filename.

I did have several images without exif data, and I was able to add exif data to the images with the command

```
exiftool -createdate='2011:12:04 12:00:00' * -overwrite_original
```

As an example, I placed some images in a directory ~/aa/test1 and ran the tool, placing the output in ~/aa/test2.  The results are below:

```
chick@dad:~/aa$ tree .
.
├── test1
│   ├── DSC00018.JPG
│   ├── DSC00022.JPG
│   ├── DSC00024.JPG
│   ├── DSC00025.JPG
│   ├── DSC00026.JPG
│   ├── DSC00028.JPG
│   ├── DSC00031.JPG
│   ├── DSC00033.JPG
│   └── Thumbs.db
└── test2
    └── 2000
        └── 12-December
            ├── 20001222_185523.JPG
            ├── 20001222_200726.JPG
            ├── 20001222_200819.JPG
            ├── 20001222_201205.JPG
            ├── 20001222_201223.JPG
            ├── 20001222_210536.JPG
            ├── 20001222_211858.JPG
            └── 20001222_215950.JPG
```

Comment: Superb! You may accept this answer, because of its simplicity :) Yesterday when I made the last edit on my answer, I realized `rename` can be used in similar way as it is made here, but I do not have time to elaborate.

Comment: @pa4080 But I still like your answer, because it will cause me to work seeper into scripting...!

Answer (score 0):

So, I assume you want a step-by-step and simple solution. 
First, I would address the problem of Whitespace and comma in the folders. 
I would first cd into the year folder and use [`rename`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/prename.1.html) to first remove Whitespace

```
rename "s/ //g" *
```

Similarly, remove comma

```
rename "s/,//g" *
```

Now that I have all the folders as desired I would create a month based list using

```
ls | grep "January" > January.txt
```

Now make folder "January"

```
mkdir January
```

Then loop thru the list using [`xargs`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/xargs.1.html) to copy their contents

```
cat January.txt | xargs -I {} cp -R {}/. ./January/
```