# Recursively move files within sub directories

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, directory

```
.
├── subdirectory-A
│   ├── 1.jpg
│   ├── 1.tif
│   ├── 2.jpg
│   ├── 2.tif
│   ├── JPEG
│   └── TIF
└── subdirectory-B
    ├── 1.jpg
    ├── 1.tif
    ├── 2.jpg
    ├── 2.tif
    ├── JPEG
    └── TIF
```

Can anyone help please? I'm trying to find a way of moving all `.tif` files into the TIF directory and all `.jpg` files into the JPEG directory by running (`mv`) in a shell script from the local parent directory.  I have been using

```
mv *.jpg JPEG/
```

within each sub directory but I need to do this job on a archive with over 17K directories and the manual option one dir at a time is not an option.

Comment: Do the TIF and JPEG already exist ?

Comment: Is there only 1 for path-depth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `rename` using `bash`’s `globstar` option:

```
shopt -s globstar
rename -n 's/.*\//$&JPEG\//' **/*.jpeg
rename -n 's/.*\//$&TIF\//' **/*.tif
```

The `-n` option lets it just output what it would do, remove it to actually perform the moving. What happens here is that `rename` goes over each e.g. `.jpeg` file in any subdirectory thanks to `**` matching any number of subdirectories. It substitutes its path (everything until the last `/`) with itself (`$&`) followed by `JPEG/`, effectively moving the file to this directory.

If your list of arguments is too long the commands above will throw an error. Use this approach to work around the shell’s `ARG_MAX` limit:

```
printf '%s\0' **/*.jpeg | xargs -0 rename -n 's/.*\//$&JPEG\//'
printf '%s\0' **/*.tif | xargs -0 rename -n 's/.*\//$&TIF\//'
```

This uses the shell builtin `printf` to build a zero-delimited argument list which is piped to `xargs` which calls `rename` with the maximum number of arguments.

#### Example run

```
$ tree
.
├── subdirectory-A
│   ├── 1.jpeg
│   ├── 1.tif
│   ├── 2.jpeg
│   ├── 2.tif
│   ├── JPEG
│   └── TIF
└── subdirectory-B
    ├── 1.jpeg
    ├── 1.tif
    ├── 2.jpeg
    ├── 2.tif
    ├── JPEG
    └── TIF
$ shopt -s globstar
$ rename -n 's/.*\//$&JPEG\//' **/*.jpeg
rename(subdirectory-A/1.jpeg, subdirectory-A/JPEG/1.jpeg)
rename(subdirectory-A/2.jpeg, subdirectory-A/JPEG/2.jpeg)
rename(subdirectory-B/1.jpeg, subdirectory-B/JPEG/1.jpeg)
rename(subdirectory-B/2.jpeg, subdirectory-B/JPEG/2.jpeg)
$ rename 's/.*\//$&JPEG\//' **/*.jpeg
$ printf '%s\0' **/*.tif | xargs -0 rename 's/.*\//$&TIF\//'
$ tree
.
├── subdirectory-A
│   ├── JPEG
│   │   ├── 1.jpeg
│   │   └── 2.jpeg
│   └── TIF
│       ├── 1.tif
│       └── 2.tif
└── subdirectory-B
    ├── JPEG
    │   ├── 1.jpeg
    │   └── 2.jpeg
    └── TIF
        ├── 1.tif
        └── 2.tif
```

Comment: Yes that did it! Thanks for your help - I still have quite a lot to learn with Linux. :)

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that comes to my mind is the following Bash loop:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
for dir in */     # or use: subdirectory*/
do
    cd "$dir"
    mv *jpg JPG/
    mv *tif TIF/
    cd ..
done
```

Example of usage as inline command:

```bsh
$ mkdir -p subdirectory-{A,B}/{TIF,JPG}; touch subdirectory-{A,B}/{1,2}.{jpg,tif}

$ for dir in */; do cd "$dir"; mv *jpg JPG/; mv *tif TIF/; cd ..; done

$ tree
.
├── subdirectory-A
│   ├── JPG
│   │   ├── 1.jpg
│   │   └── 2.jpg
│   └── TIF
│       ├── 1.tif
│       └── 2.tif
└── subdirectory-B
    ├── JPG
    │   ├── 1.jpg
    │   └── 2.jpg
    └── TIF
        ├── 1.tif
        └── 2.tif

6 directories, 8 files
```

Related questions:

- [Move files from subfolders](https://askubuntu.com/q/1110359/566421)
- [Recursive bash script to collect information about each file in a directory structure](https://askubuntu.com/q/968887/566421)

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned "over 17K directories", `find` and `xargs` spring to mind.

```
# do this part Only Once  
cat >./TheScript <<"EOF"
#!/bin/bash
while $# -gt 0 ; do
    cd "$1"
    find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.jpg' -print | xargs --no-run-if-empty mv --target-directory=JPG
    find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.tif' -print | xargs --no-run-if-empty mv --target-directory=TIF
    cd "$OLDPWD"
    shift
done
exit 0
EOF
chmod +x ./TheScript
# end of "Only Once"


find . -type d \! -name 'JPG' -a \! -name 'TIF` -print |\
    xargs $PWD/.TheScript
```