# How to rename multiple files with a command or script

Tags: rename

I have hundreds of image files (.jpg) with different names with nothing in common; e.g., 12223.jpg, beautiful-ocean.jpg, aWkqi.jpg. How can i rename them all in series, such as 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211595/renaming-files-in-a-folder-to-sequential-numbers or https://askubuntu.com/questions/301781/how-to-rename-multiple-files-sequentially-from-command-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could rename the files as `001.jpg`, `002.jpg`, ... `999.jpg` in `bash` by:

```
declare -i num=1
for file in *.jpg ; do
    printf -v newname "%03d.jpg" $num
    num=$(( num + 1 ))
    echo mv "$file" "$newname"
done
```

Change "`echo mv`" to "`mv`" when you're happy with the generated results.